# Working of Email sending in Android

Tags: android, email, mobile

I am developing an Application in android which include feature like sending emails.
 I am not getting how to start this.Did anyone tell me 
How email sending work in Android ?
I mean what are the steps to send email via android application ?

Comment: Read this: [Android Mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application)

Comment: seems like a http://google.com stops working ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548246/attaching-file-and-sending-mail-using-smtp-in-android

Answer (score 1):

this will send email via any installed mail client.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send e-mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    //you have no mail client
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send in any of the following way.

1. Throw an email implicit intent. Then available email clients will send the email for you.

   for this you can check this famouse [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197741/how-to-send-email-from-my-android-application)
2. If you want to create your own email client you can use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to send emails from your own application

Comment: lol, seems like i've been in the famous thread long time ago, my answer is a part of mine project :D